# starting kairosdb gives error when used with cassandra, new installation

Tags: java, cassandra, startup, kairosdb

> 04:39:30.558 [main] INFO  [Cluster.java:1614] - Cannot connect with protocol version V4, trying with V3
>
> 04:39:30.580 [main] INFO  [Cluster.java:1614] - Cannot connect with protocol version V3, trying with V2
>
> 04:39:30.671 [main] WARN  [Cluster.java:2202] - You listed localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042 in your contact points, but it wasn't found in the control host's system.peers at startup
>
> 04:39:30.847 [main] INFO  [KairosRetryPolicy.java:104] - Initializing KairosRetryPolicy: retry count set to 1
>   04:39:30.848 [main] INFO  [Cluster.java:1568] - New Cassandra host localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 added
>
> **04:39:31.333 [main] ERROR [CassandraModule.java:136] - Unable to setup cassandra schema
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 6:28 no viable alternative at input '>'**
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:58)
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:24)
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:68)
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:43)

Comment: do we have a proper step wise guide on installing configuring and setting up  with matching version information for kairosdb/cassandra  setup? i am new for using kairosdb and finding it difficult to setup and use. as per the site instructions it should be straight forward.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Helpful may be ["how to ask good questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Users here are way more ready to help if you provide [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with some input and the desired output.